# When processing HAR file need to get entries for one page at a time

Tags: java, har

I am trying to get the total load time for each page by parsing a HAR file.  I found a code segment where the total time is found by subtracting the time of the last get from the start of the page.  So far so good.

I have an outer loop that goes through all the pages.

```
      List<HarPage> pages = log.getPages().getPages();
        for (HarPage page : pages)
        {
        / confirms that I go through all the pages
        writer.println("\n\n***\n    Top of page loop, Page Number   :" + pageNumber);
        }



/* The problem is that I would like to process all the entries for one page  at a time.  This inner loop is not working properly and seems to go through  the entries for all the pages.  The calling sequence is as follows:
*/    
    List<HarPage> pages = log.getPages().getPages();
    for (HarPage page : pages)
    {
                        HarEntries entries = log.getEntries();
                        List<HarEntry> entryList = entries.getEntries();
                        int entryIndex = 0;
                        for (HarEntry entry : entryList) {
                        / print entry number to see how many entries it processes
                        writer.println("Page Number: " + pageNumber + "  Entry: " + entryIndex++);
                        entryIndex++;
                        }
    }
```

I have 124 entries in the first page (which I confirmed by processing the file through http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/ but my program will go through 1305 entries for all pages.

Thanks,
Tariq Badsha

PS I found out that there is a field in the Entry entry.getPageRef().  This changes when I go to the next page.  So maybe this can be used as a trigger to exit from the inner loop.  If someone has a more elegant solution Please comment
TB

Comment: Add language tag, please, it can help to attract more users to this question.

Comment: What HAR API are you using?  I don't recognise a `log.getPages().getPages()` API for instance.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Paul, thanks for responding.  I was not using an API but some library functions.  In any event, I had the work around I described above and it worked. The program is now end of life.